# What is the best way to expose only few tables from a database?

Tags: java, database, security

We have a database with just query capabilities and access to read/write data. There is another team that OFTEN needs to look at a few tables based on few parameters. We dont(will never) have the power to give the other team to look into the database. Its kind of catch 22 and kind of a great distraction to me to manually query based on a few fields look into it and send each one the details.

What is the best way so that we can just present them the view of database with less effort but a can be extendable to other tables if necessary ? [It should query them at that time. cannot just show the entire table as they are huge]

I have never built any web-services (java).. does that sound any good?

And if someone can suggest a method and give good practice ways for that it would be great.

Edit

Note: data cant be even exported or cant even use 3rd party web tools

[if you consider to be not a relevant one and close this at-least please leave comment why or where would have been appropriate because I see many #design questions of similar type]

Answer (score 6):

I'd use VIEWs and GRANT appropriate permissions.  I don't see why read-only access to a few tables would be a problem.

You can certainly use web services.  That will restrict their access.  A web UI would be a fine way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, Read-only access is not possible we dont have that prev and we cant ask one for them too. Stuck between 2 worlds

Comment: are there any  tutorials that you can suggest for webservices?

Comment: You can't throw a rock without finding web service tutorials.  I prefer Spring "contract first" web services myself.

Answer (score 3):

Building on duffymo's web UI statement:

I deployed a [Heroku](https://postgres.heroku.com/) PostgreSQL database that allows you to do this via its [Dataclips](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dataclips) feature.

The benefit to me is that I write a query once, expose it as a dataclip and give them the dataclip URL. Future data retrieval is up to the team member.

Plus they can export the data set as excel, CSV, JSON, Email it, tweet it, or embed it into a webpage etc.

If your data is confidential you will need a paid subscription to be able to use its dataclip security, otherwise a free dev database can provide dataclips with an unique URL.

Comment: Thanks.. data cant be even exported or cant even use 3rd party tools.

Comment: Gotta love restrictive requirements :-D